# Django: how to have multiple sites with different default language

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-i18n, django-sites

**The situation:**
I have a instance of Django that runs multiple sites, each site can be configured by an admin user (it doesn't use Django admin but an admin app created by me).

**The problem:**
The problem is that each site should have a different default language, and it can be changed over the time.

As I know, I have to configure the default language in the settings.py file, but **I need to change it over the time**, so I think that the best option is to save this configuration in the database and not in a file.

**My guess:**
I think that it could be done using (or replacing) the LocaleMiddleware, and check the language in the database, but I don't know exactly how make this approach and if it is a good practice.

**My questions:**

- Can I configure the default language for each site in the database?.
- Replacing the LocaleMiddleware is a good approach?.
- If not, what other approach could I implement?.